# Icon in HTML is not showing up on webpage?

Tags: html, css, icons

I'm trying to have an icon or .png show up the right of the text "username" in a login box for my website, however I can't get it to show up. I practiced making a simple html page and I can get it to appear on the screen of a simple page but cannot get it to appear next to "Username" when I try it with my login page. I tried putting code for a .png and .ico in next to the "username" and in my .css file under the associated header but can't get it to appear. the .png and .ico files are in the root folder. I've read and watched a number of tutorials, tried many different code examples, etc. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

I've tried placing this code with no luck:

```
<img src = 'sunny.png' style='vertical-align: middle' />
```

My login html code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
         $('#logo').addClass('animated fadeInDown');
         $("input:text:visible:first").focus();
     });
     $('#username').focus(function() {
      $('label[for="username"]').addClass('selected');
     });
     $('#username').blur(function() {
      $('label[for="username"]').removeClass('selected');
     });
     $('#password').focus(function() {
      $('label[for="password"]').addClass('selected');
     });
     $('#password').blur(function() {
      $('label[for="password"]').removeClass('selected');
     });
```

```css
body {
     background: url("../images/photo_bg.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
     background-size: cover;
     font-size: 16px;
     font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
     font-weight: 300;
     margin: 0;
     color: #666;
    }

    /* Typography */
    h1#title {
     font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
     font-weight: 300;
     font-size: 3.2em;
     color: white;
     text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
     margin: 0 auto;
     padding-top: 180px;
     max-width: 300px;
     text-align: center;
     position: relative;
     top: 0px;
    }

    h1#title span span {
     font-weight: 400;
    }

    h2 {
     <img style='vertical-align:middle;' src='gmail.png' width="30">
    <div style='vertical-align:middle; display:inline;'>
    Your text here
    </div>
     text-transform: uppercase;
     color: white;
     font-weight: 400;
     letter-spacing: 1px;
     font-size: 1.4em;
     line-height: 2.8em;
    }

    a {
     text-decoration: none;
     color: #666;
    }

    a:hover {
     color: #aeaeae;
    }

    p.small {
     font-size: 0.8em;
     margin: 20px 0 0;
    }


    /* Layout */
    .container {
     margin: 0;
    }

    .top {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     width: 100%;
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
     background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
     filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#99000000', endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    }

    .login-box {
     background-color: white;
     max-width: 340px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     position: relative;
     top: 80px;
     padding-bottom: 30px;
     border-radius: 5px;
     box-shadow: 0 5px 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
     text-align: center;
    }

    .login-box .box-header {
     background-color: #665851;
     margin-top: 0;
     border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    }

    .login-box label {
     font-weight: 700;
     font-size: .8em;
     color: #888;
     letter-spacing: 1px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     line-height: 2em;
    }

    .login-box input {
     margin-bottom: 20px;
     padding: 8px;
     border: 1px solid #ccc;
     border-radius: 2px;
     font-size: .9em;
     color: #888;
    }

    .login-box input:focus {
     outline: none;
     border-color: #665851;
     transition: 0.5s;
     color: #665851;
    }

    .login-box button {
     margin-top: 0px;
     border: 0;
     border-radius: 2px;
     color: white;
     padding: 10px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-weight: 400;
     font-size: 0.7em;
     letter-spacing: 1px;
     background-color: #665851;
     cursor:pointer;
     outline: none;
    }

    .login-box button:hover {
     opacity: 0.7;
     transition: 0.5s;
    }

    .login-box button:hover {
     opacity: 0.7;
     transition: 0.5s;
    }

    .selected {
     color: #665851!important;
     transition: 0.5s;
    }

    /* Animation Delay */
    #logo {
      -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
    }

    .login-box {
      -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
     <div class="container">
      <div class="top">
       <h1 id="title" class="hidden"><span id="logo">Daily <span>UI</span></span></h1>
      </div>
      <div class="login-box animated fadeInUp">
       <div class="box-header">
        <h2>Log In</h2>
       </div>
       <label for="username">Username</label>
       <br/>
       <input type="text" id="username">
       <br/>
       <label for="password">Password</label>
       <br/>
       <input type="password" id="password">
       <br/>
       <button type="submit">Sign In</button>
       <br/>
       <a href="#"><p class="small">Forgot your password?</p></a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: You want to take another stab at editing? Those Code Snippets are quite there yet :)

Comment: Is this html code in css file placed by mistake? (H2 selector)

Answer (score 0):

**Try adding :**

[Font Awesome](http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css) CSS URI

[CheatSheet](http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/) :  `placeholder="&#61447; Username"`

and `input { font-family: 'FontAwesome'; }`  into your *css*

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
         $('#logo').addClass('animated fadeInDown');
         $("input:text:visible:first").focus();
     });
     $('#username').focus(function() {
      $('label[for="username"]').addClass('selected');
     });
     $('#username').blur(function() {
      $('label[for="username"]').removeClass('selected');
     });
     $('#password').focus(function() {
      $('label[for="password"]').addClass('selected');
     });
     $('#password').blur(function() {
      $('label[for="password"]').removeClass('selected');
     });
```

```css
body {
     background: url("../images/photo_bg.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
     background-size: cover;
     font-size: 16px;
     font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
     font-weight: 300;
     margin: 0;
     color: #666;
    }

    /* Typography */
    h1#title {
     font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
     font-weight: 300;
     font-size: 3.2em;
     color: white;
     text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
     margin: 0 auto;
     padding-top: 180px;
     max-width: 300px;
     text-align: center;
     position: relative;
     top: 0px;
    }

    h1#title span span {
     font-weight: 400;
    }

    h2 {
     <img style='vertical-align:middle;' src='gmail.png' width="30">
    <div style='vertical-align:middle; display:inline;'>
    Your text here
    </div>
     text-transform: uppercase;
     color: white;
     font-weight: 400;
     letter-spacing: 1px;
     font-size: 1.4em;
     line-height: 2.8em;
    }

    a {
     text-decoration: none;
     color: #666;
    }

    a:hover {
     color: #aeaeae;
    }

    p.small {
     font-size: 0.8em;
     margin: 20px 0 0;
    }


    /* Layout */
    .container {
     margin: 0;
    }

    .top {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     width: 100%;
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
     background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
     filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#99000000', endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    }

    .login-box {
     background-color: white;
     max-width: 340px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     position: relative;
     top: 80px;
     padding-bottom: 30px;
     border-radius: 5px;
     box-shadow: 0 5px 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
     text-align: center;
    }

    .login-box .box-header {
     background-color: #665851;
     margin-top: 0;
     border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    }

    .login-box label {
     font-weight: 700;
     font-size: .8em;
     color: #888;
     letter-spacing: 1px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     line-height: 2em;
    }
    
    input { font-family: 'FontAwesome'; /* This is for the placeholder */
    
    .login-box input {
     margin-bottom: 20px;
     padding: 8px;
     border: 1px solid #ccc;
     border-radius: 2px;
     font-size: .9em;
     color: #888;
    }

    .login-box input:focus {
     outline: none;
     border-color: #665851;
     transition: 0.5s;
     color: #665851;
    }

    .login-box button {
     margin-top: 0px;
     border: 0;
     border-radius: 2px;
     color: white;
     padding: 10px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-weight: 400;
     font-size: 0.7em;
     letter-spacing: 1px;
     background-color: #665851;
     cursor:pointer;
     outline: none;
    }

    .login-box button:hover {
     opacity: 0.7;
     transition: 0.5s;
    }

    .login-box button:hover {
     opacity: 0.7;
     transition: 0.5s;
    }

    .selected {
     color: #665851!important;
     transition: 0.5s;
    }

    /* Animation Delay */
    #logo {
      -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
    }

    .login-box {
      -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
     <div class="container">
      <div class="top">
       <h1 id="title" class="hidden"><span id="logo">Daily <span>UI</span></span></h1>
      </div>
      <div class="login-box animated fadeInUp">
       <div class="box-header">
        <h2>Log In</h2>
       </div>
       <label for="username">Username</label>
       <br/>
       <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="&#61447; Username">
       <br/>
       <label for="password">Password</label>
       <br/>
       <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="&#xf084; Password">
       <br/>
       <button type="submit">Sign In</button>
       <br/>
       <a href="#"><p class="small">Forgot your password?</p></a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </body>
```